# Keeping an :after element on ellipsis

Tags: css

I want to have an icon (checkmark) behind a line with variable width.
if the line becomes too long, i want it to be truncated with ellipsis.
But the checkmark is supposed to stay AFTER the ellipsis

https://jsfiddle.net/Lkvt39re/

```css
.inner {
  width: 80%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.inner::after {
  content: 'X';
}

.outer {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    this is pretty longggggg
  </div>
</div>
```

i've set the width to 80%, and want to have the `:after`inserted ..well, after the ellipsis.

how can i do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try adding a `::before` pseudo element instead, then style it to float right. This way, your pseudo content won't become trimmed out by the restrictions set to the element width.

**CSS**

```
.inner::before {
    content: 'X';
    float: right;
}
```

**Alternatively**

You can set the `::after` pseudo element to the parent element `.outer`, then set the nested `.inner` element to display `inline-block` (allowing the pseudo element of `.outer` to fall after initial width of `.inner`) with a `max-width` declared; once this `max-width` is exceeded your overflow rule will apply, giving you the ellipsis but still keeping the pseudo element of `.outer` visible after the `text-overflow`.

The problem is trying to declare this pseudo element to an element that you've also declared width restrictions and overflow rules to. You'll need to declare the pseudo element outside of the element that will, at some point, begin trimming out content.

```css
.inner {
  width: 80%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.inner::before {
    content: 'X';
    float: right;
}

.outer {
  width: 200px;
}

/* Alternative */

.alternative .inner {
    max-width: 80%;
    width: auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    display: inline-block;
}

.alternative .inner.no-max-width {
    max-width: none;
}

.alternative .inner::before {
    display: none;
}

.alternative.outer::after {
    content: 'X';
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    this is pretty longggggg
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<p><strong>Alternative</strong></p>
<div class="alternative outer">
  <div class="inner">
    this is pretty longgggggggggggg
  </div>
</div>
  
<div class="alternative outer">  
  <div class="inner no-max-width">
    this is pretty long
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: unfortunately, this doesn't work when it's NOT overflowing. in that case, i want it to be right after the text..

Comment: @devman I've updated the answer to include an alternative, have a look.

Answer (score 1):

Devman, 
You need to give the pseudo element some shape and define it as either an inline-block or a block element to do so. You can then set the dimensions appropriate to your styling.

Check out this edit:

```
.inner {
  width: 80%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  position:relative;
  /** give your container some extra space for the pseudo **/ 
  padding-right: 25px;
}

.inner::after {
  content: 'X';
  color:red;
  /** define it as a "block" element and add dimension **/
  display: inline-block;
  height: 1.0rem;
  width: 1.0rem;

}

.outer {
  width: 180px;
}
```

http://codepen.io/jonrandahl/pen/rLMKwR

Answer (score 1):

If you need to keep `::after` pseudo element, you can make it absolute positioned by adding to `.inner::after` block:

```
   position: absolute;
   right: 0;
   top: 0;
```

And you should make the parent block `.inner` to be relative positioned by adding to it

```
    position: relative;
```

Also you need to reserve some space for "X" at the right side of the `.inner` block by adding a right padding to it, e.g.

```
  padding-right: 1em;
```

Try this:

```css
.inner {
  width: 80%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  position: relative;
  padding-right: 1em;
}

.inner::after {
  content: 'X';
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.outer {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    this is pretty longgggggggggggggggggggg
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with flexbox instead of pseudo-element. See [updated example](https://jsfiddle.net/ncp27yu1/17/), cf. also a [css-tricks article on this](https://css-tricks.com/using-flexbox-and-text-ellipsis-together/):

```css
.inner {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.keep {
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.outer {
  display: flex;
  gap: 0.25rem;
  width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <span class="inner">
    this is pretty longggggg
  </span>
  <span class="keep">X</span>
</div>
```